# set contentView via openGL works very slowly

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, bitmap

In my app I'm getting data from the camera , creating `bitmap` object and I must show it using `openGL` , so for that I have `Square` class and  `GlRenderer` class. Problem is that it works very slowly , and every time it shows some image , then black screen , and another image and so on. Below is my classes

```
Square class


package com.example.videochat;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;


public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices
    private float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V1 - bottom left
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,        // V2 - top left
             1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V3 - bottom right
             1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f         // V4 - top right
    };


    private Bitmap m_bitmap;

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    private float texture[] = {         
            // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
    };

    /** The texture pointer */
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Square(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes

        m_bitmap = bitmap;
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);

        // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }


    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {

        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
//      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
//      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, m_bitmap, 0);

        // Clean up
        m_bitmap.recycle();
    }


    /** The draw method for the square with the GL context */
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // bind the previously generated texture
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        // Point to our vertex buffer
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

GlRenderer class

```
package com.example.videochat;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {

    private Square      square;     // the square
    private Context     context;

    /** Constructor to set the handed over context */
    public GlRenderer(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.context = context;
        // initialise the square
        this.square = new Square(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Reset the Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Drawing
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
                                                // is the same as moving the camera 5 units away
//      gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);          // scale the square to 50% 
                                                // otherwise it will be too large
        square.draw(gl);                        // Draw the triangle

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
            height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

        //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Load the texture for the square
        square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

        //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 

    }

}
```

and the part of tha `main` class

```
public void initGlSurfaceView (Bitmap bmp, SurfaceView VideoCaptureBitmap) {
        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GlRenderer(this,bmp));
        setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    }

    private void startVideo() {
        if(m_Camera != null) return;
        SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = null;
        try {
            m_Camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("CameraTest", "Camera Open filed");
            return;
        }
        m_Camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
            }
        }); 
        Camera.Parameters parameters = m_Camera.getParameters();
        //parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);

        List<Size> supportedPreviewSizes=parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Iterator<Size> supportedPreviewSizesIterator=supportedPreviewSizes.iterator();
        while(supportedPreviewSizesIterator.hasNext()){
            Size tmpSize=supportedPreviewSizesIterator.next();
            Log.v("CameraTest","supportedPreviewSize.width = "+tmpSize.width+"supportedPreviewSize.height = "+tmpSize.height);
        }

        m_Camera.setParameters(parameters);
        if (null != m_VideoCaptureView)
            videoCaptureViewHolder = m_VideoCaptureView.getHolder();
        try {
            m_Camera.setPreviewDisplay(videoCaptureViewHolder);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        Log.v("CameraTest","Camera PreviewFrameRate = "+m_Camera.getParameters().getPreviewFrameRate());
        Size previewSize=m_Camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width*
                               (ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(m_Camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));
        m_Camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        m_Camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        m_Camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        m_Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            private long timestamp=0;
            public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //Log.v("CameraTest","Time Gap = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-timestamp));
                //int size = data.length;

                //Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, size);
                //m_VideCaptureBitmap.setImageBitmap(btmp);


                Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize(); 
                YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 80, baos);
                byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();

                // Convert to Bitmap
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
                //m_VideCaptureBitmap.setImageBitmap(bmp);


                initGlSurfaceView(bmp, m_VideCaptureBitmap);
                // set our renderer to be the main renderer with
                // the current activity context

                //setContentView(glSurfaceView);



                Log.v("CameraTest","Frame size = "+ data.length);
                timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
                try{
                    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("CameraTest", "addCallbackBuffer error");
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }
        });

        try {
            m_Camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            m_Camera.release();
            m_Camera = null;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Can anybody helps me? Thanks
Regards